# Does a USB HID device on iOS require MFI registration?

Tags: ios, usb, hid, mfi

We develop various USB based devices which typically use USB HID with a custom protocol. We have prototyped some USB HID apps on Android, but I don't seem to be able to find a clear answer as to whether we would need to register with the MFi programme to be able to connect our devices to iOS. I know that Bluetooth Low Energy/Smart devices do not require MFi registration.

Do we have to register as MFi developers to be able to access a device over USB HID from an iOS app?